# Finite-valued condition of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

In page 28 of Real Analysis by Stein, it is stated that if $f$ is finite-valued then it is measurable iff the sets $\{a<f<b\}$ are measurable for every $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I cannot understand why the finite-valued condition is necessary. Because $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a<f<a+n\}=\{a<f\}$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$. For the reverse side, $\{f<b\}\cap \{a<f\}=\{a<f<b\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a<f<a+n\}=\{a<f\}$ is false if $f$ is allowed to take the value $\infty$. (Note that LHS is contained in $\{x:f(x)<\infty\}$).  If $f\equiv \infty I_A -\infty I_{A^{c}}$ where $A$ is not measurable  thne $\{a<f<b\}$ is empty, hence measurable for all $a,b$ but $f$ is not measurable because $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})=A$ is not measurable.

Comment: Yes, I had seen this example before, but I was wondering to know where I did a mistake in my solution above to show that they are equivalent without using the assumption of finiteness of $f$.

Comment: @S_Alex I have added some more lines to my answer.